# chrome.storage not working and is blocking the processes underneath

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried to save some data to chrome local storage. I've been using this ever since and its working fine. However, just yesterday it stops working.

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ 'test': 'this is an awesome test' }, res => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log('runtime errorsss');
            }

            console.log('Response: ', res);
        });
```

This doesn't even return any error. And whatever processes I have after this code is not called. I know this is asynchronous, but my problem really is why it doesn't process the storing and return any Promise.

Please let me know if you have any idea why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: Do any of the `console.log`s log anything?

Comment: Use the `localStorage.setItem({ 'test': 'this is an awesome test' });` for set data to localStorage in Chrome. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) you can see example.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when the code is run?

Comment: Assuming you have debugged it in devtools and it didn't help, the problem may be caused by a corrupted database file in the user profile. The usual method is to isolate it - install the extension in a new (portable) browser or in a new user profile and see if the problem is reproducible.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried installing it on a different profile but same result.

Comment: @Cerbrus nothing.

Comment: @IvanRubinson no errors.

Comment: It can only mean two things: 1) a bug in the browser, 2) a bug in your code (which is not shown in the question) that got triggered for an unknown reason.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think its on my listener. The code shown on my question is inside an async function which listens for updates. When the update is done, it will update the data stored into chrome. However, it just stops right on saving the updated data into the chrome storage.

Comment: Without seeing more code or the entire extension, there's nothing else I can add.

Comment: @wOxxOm I already fixed it. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it! :)